# Why doesn't highcharts refresh this chart correctly?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts is failing to refresh my chart in any kind of intelligent way.This seems like a fairly common use case:

I am rendering an area percentage chart, which renders perfectly the first time. At some point the data changes and I want to refresh the chart.

The word on the streets is that I should manually iterate my data and call setData on each series. The problem with this approach is that the series are not guaranteed to be the same when I am trying to refresh. So there are edge cases where using this technique would mismatch data.

I tried this :

```
data = this.getAreaChartData();

if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {

var dataLength = data.length;
for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < dataLength; dataIndex++) {

    var currentSeries = data[dataIndex];

    this.chart.series[dataIndex] = currentSeries;

}
```

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that getAreaChartData() produces perfectly valid data. When I set the series like this nothing happens and the chart gets buggy.

I try to call `chart.redraw()` just to see if I can force it and still nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `update` to update a serie with a new set of options.
Like the following:

```
data = this.getAreaChartData();

var dataLength = data.length,
    chart = this.chart;
for( var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < dataLength; dataIndex++ ) {

    // add series without redraw, we'll redraw later
    chart.series[ dataIndex ].update( data[dataIndex], false );
}

chart.redraw();
```

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.update()

Answer (score 0):

You should use setData function after updating the data in your series. Only then highcharts would come to know that you have made changes in your data. It makes more sense to use setData as compared to update function as it is mentioned in the docs that update function is more expensive (performance wise). 
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.update